# How to add: "Open With" other apps option in UIWebview when viewing Documents (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiwebview, ios8

I was wondering if anyone could show me what code I need to implement to make my webview present options when viewing a document. Currently now I have a simple View controller with a webView taking up the entire view. It works fine and can display the documents but thats it. Shown below is an image from the safari iOS App that has the functionality I'm looking for.

Image Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/i32EO.jpg
(Because I don't have enough reputation to upload image.. : /

Any help will be greatly appreciated. The tutorials I come across only show how to make the UIWebView work and it stops just about there.

Answer (score 0):

-when you top long time on you web view and show "open in..." button on the top of web view.

click it then show like this:

[image]

```
- (void)SetmyParentViewController:(id)pViewController 
{
    if (nil != pmyParentViewController) {
    }
    self.pmyParentViewController = (UIViewController *)pViewController;
}

- (BOOL)SelectAppToOpenFile:(NSURL *)aUrl;
{
    if (nil == pDocInteractCtrl) {
        self.pDocInteractCtrl = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:aUrl];
        pDocInteractCtrl.delegate = (id)self.pmyParentViewController;
    } else {
        [pDocInteractCtrl setURL:aUrl];
    }
    if ([pDocInteractCtrl presentOpenInMenuFromRect:viewRect inView:pmyParentViewController.view animated:YES]) {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do this using swift code? Also do I just paste these functions straight into the view controller file after viewDidLoad? & finally, Are there any outlets that need to be connected also?